# Measuring video streaming quality

Tags: java, video-streaming

I am working on an app to measure the video streaming quality from a web site and I am using Java. I searched internet for this a bit but couldn't find any pointers or resources. What do I need to do to measure video streaming quality ? Any hints/pointers for writing a Java code to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [An Innovative Tool for Measuring Video Streaming QoE](http://www2.alcatel-lucent.com/techzine/an-innovative-tool-for-measuring-video-streaming-qoe/)